# Web based emulator for classic video games?

Tags: webapp-rec

I've seen one that was a firefox extension, and plenty to download, but is there a website that I can visit to just play old NES games? Online, no downloads, etc.

I'm not looking for a directory site like addictinggames.com, or a site with a bunch of knock offs, but somewhere to play the original games in 8 bit form.

Comment: Totally off topic, but have you tried out orisinal.com?

Comment: Okay, this isn't actually an emulator for multiple games, hence not an answer, but if you are a fan of Mario, check out http://supermariobroscrossover.com/ . You can play Super Mario Bros as any one of several other classic characters... such as the Contra guy.  :)

Comment: Does [DHTML lemmings](http://www.elizium.nu/scripts/lemmings) count?

Answer (score 0):

I found the following from Google, but I can't vouch for them as I never had a NES myself.

[Nintendo8](http://nintendo8.com)

[1980-Games](http://www.1980-games.com/us/old-games/nintendo/nintendo-games.php)

[NES Forever](http://www.nesforever.com)

[NEScafe Web](http://www.nescafeweb.com)

Comment: 1980-Games looks pretty sweet... I'll give it a shot...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pretty cool NES emulator: [JSNES](http://benfirshman.com/projects/jsnes/) and it doesn't require any browser plugin, HTML5-based, it runs faster in very recent browsers.

Comment: That's pretty cool. The name is misleading though, it's an NES emulator, not SNES. The "JS" stands for JavaScript.

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to have JAVA installed, but this should get you going: [VirtualNES](http://www.virtualnes.com)